# JMSI18nRoutingBundle and translatable routes catalog location

Tags: symfony, routes, internationalization

I am using JMSI18nRoutingBundle for internalisation of the routes of an application and it is some nice piece of software but unfortunately not very well documented and I am not sure how to achieve the translation of the strings in the routes for the different locales regardless of the fact it is given as an example in the docs.

What I would like is to have (default local without prefix, all others translated and with locale prefix):

/contact
/de/kontakt

The problem is with the following configuration:

```
jms_i18n_routing:
default_locale: en
locales: [en, de]
strategy: prefix_except_default
```

The routes are generated as:

/contact
/de/contact

I could not see a setting where to input kontakt for the de route, is it part of some special message catalog or per-route configuration option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that it is handled by the translations catalog. The routes are loaded from it. There is a command to extract them from the router and put them into the catalog:

```
php bin/console translation:extract LANGUAGE --bundle=BUNDLE --enable-extractor=jms_i18n_routing --output-format=xliff --dir=RESOURCE_FOLDER --domain=routes
```

Where LANGUAGE is the target language, BUNDLE is the bundle to extract the routes from and RESOURCE_FOLDER is where to put the translations.